# Selective copying maven resources

Tags: java, maven, resources

I have a Java application build under maven. It contains two properties files - application.default.properties and application.properties. The second one suppose to supplement and/or overwrite some properties. I do have also logback.xml file in the same src/main/resources directory.
I want to keep logging and default properties in the jar file but move application.properies to the root of the tree. I put the following piece into the build section of my pom.xml

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${user.dir}</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

It does copy the application.properties file as expected, but other two files disappeared from the jar file.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to alleviate the problem.
P.S. I did browse maven documentation but couldn't find the answer there, so please do not tell me RTFM, but if it is there provide a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is another `<resource>` section that would include *application.default.properties* and *logback.xml* and treat them differently.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${user.dir}</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This copies *application.properties* into `${user.dir}`, and packages everything else from *src/main/resources* into the output jar.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move that specific file you want at the root to another directory.

What you did with the include pattern is implicitly excluding the other files. If you include them, they will be moved as well.